# Itext7 - write multiple documents on single pdf

Tags: java, itext7

I'm writing multiple PdfDocument on a single pdf. The PdfDocument are generated populating PdfAcroForm of different templates.
My solution actually works, but I think it is not very efficent.
Is there a more efficent way to have the same result?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream globalBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument pdfDocGlobal = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(globalBaos));
for (Documento document : docs) {
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(document.getPath());
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos);
   PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
   Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

   [.... populate pdfDoc ]
   doc.close();
   pdfDoc.close();
   baos.close();
//read again the closed document to copy it in the globalBaos 
  PdfDocument dr = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())));
   dr.copyPagesTo(1, dr.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDocGlobal);
   dr.close();
}

pdfDocGlobal.close();
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(FILE_OUTPUT);
output.write(globalBaos.toByteArray());
output.close();
globalBaos.close();
```

Comment: You use `dr.copyPagesTo` without `IPdfPageExtraCopier` argument. Thus, form information might not properly be added to the target document form dictionary. Furthermore, you'll likely have form field name collisions.Unless you flattened the forms, that is. Other than that the approach looks sensible.

Comment: Why collisions? at each iteration the inner document is closed and than resetted.Moreover, is there another way to write the inner document in the global one without reading it all again?

Comment: Collisions, if the different source documents have fields with the same name, at least if you want to fill them differently. Otherwise no collision.

Comment: sure, it can happen that source document have fields with same names. How can avoid collisions?

Comment: *"How can avoid collisions?"* - by renaming the fields accordingly, e.g. by adding a name prefix which is unique for each source document.